# configuring handlers :Axis2 ,Rampart

Tags: apache-axis, ws-security, rampart

I currently have a handler to check if action given in SOAPAction field of HTTP header and the actual operation are the same.I have followed the Axis2 tutorial and I get this exception :

Deployment exception for the handler
And WSDoAllReceiver Security processing failed

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you have the rampart module engaged. If your handler is simply checking the SOAPAction and you do not need any security processing, please remove rampart module and try.